# How can I remove default button?

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I remove dafult button to place my custom button in navbar? Problem at the moment is that my custom button is over default button. [image]

Please take a look at the screenshot and it will be more clear.

I'm getting this with following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barMenuButton.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:menuImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(ShowLeftMenu:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem:

```
UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barMenuButton.png"];

UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40);
[button setImage:menuImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[addButton setAction:@selector(ShowLeftMenu:)];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom view and add that to the bar button item, as described in [this article](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/06/11/iphone-adding-image-to-uibarbuttonitem/). [This article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33427366406/designing-for-ios-taming-uibutton) also provides some details about creating custom `UIButtons`.